# Removing Keys from hashmap thru composite key value

Tags: java

Hey guys currently have problem with regards to removing duplicates from hashmap.

Some background:

My hashmap is in this format `Map<CompositeKeyBean,ValueBean>`.

`CompositeKeyBean` is in the form `(String ID, String hashvalue)`;

`ValueBean` is an object.

So if i have a hashmap with values as such:

```
(ID:1,HashValue:123),Obj1
(ID:1,HashValue:234),Obj1
(ID:1,HashValue:345),Obj1
```

I need to remove the duplicate keys and only have items with unique IDs. currently I have come up with this, But it does not seem to work, im pretty sure i am doing something wrong.

```
for (Map.Entry<CompositeKeyBean, ReportDataBean> entry : list.entrySet())
    {
        String idvalue = entry.getKey().getCompositeKeyList().get(0);
        for(int i = 1; i < list.size();i++)
        {
            if(list.keySet().contains(idvalue))
            {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A generally better approach is to use a set of already seen IDs. Iterate through the map. If an ID is not in the seen set, add it. If it is, delete entry from map.

Comment: Your `CompositeKeyBean` has `getCompositeKeyList` method, not just in the form of `ID, Hash`. I'm pretty sure your code is not compiled OR you did not provide the complete/correct description

Comment: Yes, CompositeKeyBean contains a list of strings. Currently, what happens is the user will be able to define the identifier for their records, some records have the same ID but will have different payment values, so what the user will do is:

Store the ID and the hashvalue of the other values in their payment details to the compositekeybean. the getCompositeKeyList() method just returns the entire list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this one would be to declare first an another Map which will be used to hold the number of times that a certain key has appeared in the original Map. For the second time, you can iterate the same map entrySet and remove the duplicates using the declared additional Map as reference.

```
Map<String, Integer> numberOfInstanceMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); //temporary placeholder

for (Map.Entry<CompositeKeyBean, ReportDataBean> entry : list.entrySet())
{
    String idvalue = entry.getKey().getCompositeKeyList().get(0);
    if(!numberOfInstanceMap.containsKey(idvalue)) {
        numberOfInstanceMap.put(idvalue, 1); //initialize the key to 1
    } else {
        numberOfInstanceMap.replace(idValue, numberOfInstanceMap.get(idValue) + 1); //add 1 to the existing value of the key
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<CompositeKeyBean, ReportDataBean> entry : list.entrySet())
{
    String idvalue = entry.getKey().getCompositeKeyList().get(0);
    Integer i = numberOfInstanceMap.get(idValue);
    if(i>1) { //remove duplicate if the key exists more than once
        list.remove(idValue);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting duplicate keys, then you can do the following way to handle it while populating the map itself:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

if(map.containsKey("ID")){
String oldValue = map.get("ID");
//put logic to merge the value
}else{
map.put("ID","newValue");
}
```